# Not able to write into text file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to write a string into a file. For that, my code is:

```
-(void)writeToFile:(NSString *)fileName: (NSString *)data {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    // the path to write file
    NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [data writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];  
}
```

I am calling this method like this

```
ownServices *obj = [[ownServices alloc]init];
[obj writeToFile:@"iphone.txt" :@"this is mahesh babu"];
```

but it didn't write into the text file.

What's the reason? Can anyone please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: Did it give an error?  If so, what?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and verify the string before you call write to file.

Comment: yes i am getting string this is mahesh babu at data and file path at appfile.

Comment: How do you know the file isn't written to?

Comment: after written into file again read that file,At that time there is new ly written string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are calling your method strangely. Rename the method to

```
-(void)writeString:(NSString *) data toFile:(NSString *)fileName
```

and call it like so:

```
[obj writeString:@"this is mahesh babu" toFile:@"iphone.txt"];
```

Secondly, `writeToFile:atomically:` is deprecated, use `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`:

```
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [data writeToFile:appFile  atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8Encoding error:&error];
if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error userInfo]);
}
```

This way, you also see what the error is.

Comment: The idea of error checking is correct, but the implementation is wrong. You need to check the return value from the method before using the NSError object. It's stated in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-BAJIIGCC)

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that one. But at least it would have shown if the error is really coming from writing to the file.

Comment: Okay - I've edited your code and reversed the downvote. Feel free to rollback.

Comment: I had thought it was enough to check if error was != nil (usually it is, isn't it?). Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Nope - For Cocoa methods that indirectly return error objects, if the method call fails, and you have passed in a reference to an NSError object, then the error object is guaranteed to be valid. You only need to check the return value of the method.

Comment: i did n't get any error,after write into file i am reading that file. Unfortunately i did n't found the string what i write into that.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely problem is that the documents directory does not exist. Create it if it doesn't, then write to it:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
        NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *parentDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

/* Create the parent directory.
 * This is expected to fail if the directory already exists. */
(void)[[NSFileManager defaultManager]
       createDirectoryAtPath:parentDir
       withIntermediateDirectories:YES
       attributes:nil error:NULL];
NSString *path = [parentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

/* Now write, and if it fails, you'll know why thanks to the |error| arg. */
NSError *error = nil;
BOOL ok = [data writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
if (!ok) {
    NSLog(@"%s: Failed to write to %@: %@", __func__, path, error);
}
```

Even simpler would be to use the latest API, which will create the directory for you if it doesn't already exist:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *parentURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
    URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
    appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:&error];
if (!parentURL) {
    NSLog(@"%s: *** Failed to get documents directory: %@", __func__, error):
    return;
}

NSURL *furl = [parentURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
error = nil;
BOOL ok = [data writeToURL:furl options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
if (!ok) {
    NSLog(@"%s: *** Failed to write to %@: %@", __func__, furl, error);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks OK. Use the debugger (or an `NSLog` statement) to verify the values of `data` and `appFile`. If `data` is `nil`, nothing will happen (including no errors) because sending a message to `nil` is a no-op. It's also possible that `appFile` is not the path you think it is.

Check the permissions of the directory you are trying to write to (`ls -la`). On the device you can't, but on the simulator you can. Is it read-only for you? Is it owned by another user?

Assuming that isn't the problem, try calling with `atomically:NO`. Atomic file writing is performed by writing a file, then renaming it to replace the old one. If the problem is there, that will isolate the problem.

### Bonus Style Critique

- Class names should start with an uppercase letter: `OwnServices` instead of `ownServices`
- Although your method name is perfectly valid, it's unusual to have two parameters with no words to separate them. A name like `writeToFile:string:` would be better.
- Don't name a variable `data` if it is meant to point to an instance of something other than `NSData`. It's confusing, and there's almost a better (more specific) word you can use beside "data".

Comment: Here's a fuller one, for anyone who's interested [Cocoa API Conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/AddingBehaviortoaCocoaProgram/AddingBehaviorCocoa.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH5-SW29)

Comment: Haha, I thought you wrote **he's** a [fuller one](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fuller) ...